# PHP extensions not loading on IIS

Tags: php, iis, extension

Calling a function that loads an extension (curl, mysqli, etc.) throws a PHP fatal error. I've looked all over the internets but all the things found did not resolve. Here is a list of findings and details:

- PHP 5.6.14 NTS located in c:\php
- confirmed this is set in PATH
- extension_dir specified as c:\php\ext
- extension files are present
- error logging to event viewer, no errors logged
- extensions are set in php.ini
- confirmed loading php.ini from c:\php
- added IUSR read and execute access to c:\php\*

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the exact error message?  What does your configuration file look like?  What does `phpinfo()` have to say about loaded extensions?

Comment: The error was the following:

`PHP Fatal Error: call to undefined function mysql_connect()`

phpinfo() said the extensions loaded fine

Answer (score -1):

SOLVED: restarted Windows... :(

Comment: What did you solve and how?

Comment: No clue - but I restarted Windows and the error was no longer appearing.